# lambda expressions improve cod

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to improve own code.I'm new to lambda expressions.
My Code:

```
protected void Process1(List<SomeClass>mylist)
{
                foreach(var item in mylist)
                {
                               if (!SomeClass.Validate(item))
                               {
                                               continue;
                               }
                               DoStuff(item);
                               DoMoreStuff(item);
                               DoEvenMoreStuff(item);
                }
}

protected void Process2(List<SomeClass>mylist)
{
                foreach(var item in mylist)
                {
                               if (!SomeClass.Validate(item) || item.Value == 0)
                               {
                                               continue;
                               }
                               DoStuff(item);
                               DoMoreStuff(item);
                               DoEvenMoreStuff(item);
                }
}
```

Can it will be improved by using a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only a very small part of the code differs between the methods, you could use lambdas by passing in a lambda that does the validation and remove some of the redundant code;

```
protected void Process1(List<SomeClass>mylist) {
    Process (mylist, item => !SomeClass.Validate (item));
}

protected void Process2(List<SomeClass>mylist) {
    Process (mylist, item => !SomeClass.Validate (item) || item.Value == 0);
}

private void Process(List<SomeClass>mylist, Func<SomeClass, bool> validator)
{
    foreach (var item in mylist) {
        if (validator (item)) {
            continue;
        }
        DoStuff (item);
        DoMoreStuff (item);
        DoEvenMoreStuff (item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you create your own slightly worse and not generalized version of `Where`?

Comment: @Servy I thought the other answers covered the conversion to `Where` sufficiently, so I chose to keep the question's code structure. Naturally, this can be combined with the other answers by just using `foreach (var item in mylist.Where(i => !validator(i)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace your `if` statements with a `Where` clause:

```
foreach (var item in mlist.Where(i => !SomeClass.Validate(i) || i.Value == 0))
{
   DoStuff(item);
   ...
}
```

Depending on what those functions do, they could be improved as well, but this is the only improvement I see from what was given.

Answer (score 0):

> Can it will be improved by using a lambda expression?

Not really.  Code is improved with lambda expressions and LINQ when it makes the code easier to understand.  In other words, if the code is best described as declarative, or as a mapping from one space to another, LINQ and lambda expressions give your code more expressive power.

Modifying BrandleyDotNet's answer for slightly more clarity gives this:

```
var nonValidItems = mList.Where(item => !SomeClass.Validate(item) || item.Value == 0));
foreach (item in nonValidItems)
{
    DoStuff(item);
}
```

But does this really help your code?  Not necessarily.  The introduction of LINQ doesn't offer much more in the way of expressiveness for a case like this.